# How to use Hapi.js to serve a static HTML index

Tags: javascript, html, express, hapi.js

With express.js i can do this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = 9200;

var path = require('path');

var options = {
    index: "html/index.html"
};



app.use('/', express.static('res', options));
server.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port " + port);
```

How do i achieve the same thing using Hapi.js?

I have tried some things also with inertjs but I can't seem to find the correct way. Does anyone have experience with it?

Found my way to this implementation, but im getting TypeErrors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined

```
server.register(require('inert'), (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/index',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply.file('C:/blabla/html/index.html');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by using Hapi@16.x.x and Inert@4.x.x and using Ernest Jones answer.

For anyone dealing with this problem in the future here is my complete change:

```
const Hapi = require('hapi');
const Inert = require('inert');
const server = new Hapi.Server();

server.connection({port: 9200});


server.register(Inert, (err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/index',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply.file('/res/html/index.html');
        }
    });
    server.route({
        path: "/res/{path*}",
        method: "GET",
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: "./res",
                listing: false,
                index: false
            }
        }});


});
server.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [doc](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files)

In detail, you just have to call reply.file()

This will not work with hapi 17 because of the major change in the request system

```
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/picture.jpg',
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply.file('/path/to/picture.jpg');
        }
    });
```

Comment: I figured it was the server.routes, will try.

Comment: Is it the absolute path to my index? c:/users/username/webstormprojects/projectname/index.html ??

Comment: I would say to your project root, where there is your package.json but, I am not sure, you should try both... and validate my answer ^^

Comment: Doing it as above mentioned gives me unhandled promise rejection and deprecationwarning

Comment: Pretty sure you are using hapi 17

Comment: Yeah thats the problem, ill try downgrading it.

Comment: You can stay with hapi 17 but I will be no help

Comment: Changed to hapi 16.6.0 and now im getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined, check my edited code at top.

Comment: Did you instantiate your server object ?

Comment: Yes, i think it might have to do with using inert 5.xx, instead of 4.xx

Comment: You’re sure you create the server like const server = new hapi.server() ?

Comment: Yep i did, its also working now, however its not showing my CSS on my homepage

Comment: That’s an other issue, it’s not anymore linked to hapi but the way you manage your front. Glad I helped. Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for the help :)